# Android conectar no Postgres

Tags: android, postgresql

Tenho uma aplicação, e quero usar o banco de dados postgres, esse banco está em um servidor, e eu consigo acessar esse servidor, como faço a conexão. Não sei se expliquei direito, mas acho que da pra entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dizem que uma imagem vale mais do que 1000 palavras... e uma apresentação?

Brincadeiras a parte, uma apresentação da PostgreSQL Conference 2011 explica direitinho como fazer:

[Android & PostgreSQL](http://www.pgcon.org/2011/schedule/track/Applications/278.en.html)

Comment: muito obrigado, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Espero que de certo!

Comment: meu ingles não é dos melhores, mas da pra arranhar kkkkk

Comment: sempre tem google translate ;D

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira você poderia trazer um resumo para cá? Respostas que contenham apenas links podem se tornar inválidas com tempo, além de dificultar outras pessoas acharem o conteúdo aqui.